# lowdb: update record at index N

Tags: javascript, node.js

I'm using `lowdb` (https://github.com/typicode/lowdb) with a persistent storage (`file-async`):

```
const low = require('lowdb');
const db = low('db.json', {storage: require('lowdb/lib/storages/file-async')});
db.defaults({inputs: []}).value();
```

From a client I receive this object:

```
var data = {
  "idx": 1,
  "item": { "Name": "blabla", "Surname": "bleble" }
}
```

I want to update the record number `idx` with the new information received. This doesn't update anything:

```
if (data.idx < db.get("inputs").size()) {
    db.get("inputs").nth(data.idx)
        .assign(data.item)
        .write();
}
```

In my actual data I have more than 2 items.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here the solution:

```
db.get('inputs')
    .nth(data.idx)
    .assign(data.item)
    .value();
db.write();
```

Please note the last method should be a separate call. Putting the `write()` call at the end of the chain **doesn't work**, at least in my setup.